# Simple association architecture and implementation in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, nested-attributes, simple-form

Quick question about a simple problem I am facing (and I want to use as a way to understand a few things about associations and rails in a deeper level). Here goes:

The two associated models are

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  attr_accessible :age

  belongs_to :role
  attr_accessible :role_id
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title
  attr_accessible :salary

  has_many :employees
end
```

so that every new employee has a fixed salary, according to his role (which is the case most of the times). However, what if I want to set a different salary for a specific employee?

Using `simple_form` I have so far written the following:

```
<%= f.input :name, label: 'Employee Name', :required => true %>
<%= f.association :role, as: :radio_buttons, :required => true %>
<%= f.input :salary, label: 'Employee Salary', :input_html => { :value => 0 }, :required => true %>
```

Which of course gives me a `can't mass assign protected attributes: salary` error.

To fix that, I added `attr_accessible :salary` to the `Employee` model but that just changed the error to `unknown attribute: salary`.

From what I understand I have to first change something in the new employee and then also in the employee model and controller so it accepts a value for the salary and knows how to handle it, right?

I 've also seen `accepts_nested_attributes_for` used but I am not entirely sure in which side of the association it should go - as I am not entirely sure the association is architectured in the best way either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `salary` column to your `employees` table if you are in fact wanting to allow a custom salary to be specified **on** the `Employee`. In your terminal, create a new migration and apply it

```
rails generate migration AddSalaryToEmployees salary:integer
RAILS_ENV=development rake db:migrate
```

By the way, you don't need to call `attr_accessible` multiple times; it accepts an arbitrary # of symbols

```
attr_accessible :name, :age, :role_id, :salary
```

Also, since you mentioned it, I'll comment on it: `accepts_nested_attributes_for` currently has no place in your models (given the code you've shown so far).

---

To answer the questions raised in your comment:

> Isn't that duplication of code (having salary in both models I mean)?

No, they serve two different purposes. `:salary` in `Role` is the default salary applied to all `Employees` associated with that `Role`. `:salary` on `Employee` is an 'override' for special circumstances where an `Employee`'s salary doesn't fit the mold of the `Role` they're associated with.

- It wouldn't make sense to create a custom `Role` just for this purpose (assuming the custom salary is the only difference for the `Employee`)
- You can't change the salary on the `Role` itself, because that would affect the salary of the other `Employees` associated with that `Role`

> And doesn't that need another method (to make sure that the role salary is set as the employee's salary if none is specifically set)?

Another method? No. Customizing the existing attr_reader for `salary` on `Employee` to return the default from the `Role` if an 'override' hasn't been set? If you want

```
def salary
  return role.salary if read_attribute(:salary).blank?
  read_attribute(:salary)
end
```

Comment: Isn't that duplication of code (having `salary` in both models I mean)? And doesn't that need another method (to make sure that the role salary is set as the employee's salary if none is specifically set)? (I am calling `attr_accessible` numerous times because I don't like to have all the attributes I one line, I guess I should just call it one and indent all the attributes in different rows though)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was under the impression that I should avoid what you describe to be just fine. Thanks for the clarification about the `salary` method as well. :)

Comment: I just did, but I wonder if `read_attribute(:salary).blank? ? role.salary : read_attribute(:salary)` is a "rubier" way to write the `salary` method?

Comment: That's pretty subjective, but I'd say **no**. Also, a ternary operator like you're suggesting is a bit less readable to me. As a one-liner I'd even prefer `read_attribute(:salary) || role.salary` over the ternary operator.