# simple_form f.association as: :radio_buttons with different values and ids for jQuery manipulation

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, radio-button, associations, simple-form

Continuing from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664449/simple-association-architecture-and-implementation-in-ruby-on-rails) (where an `employee belongs_to role` and has a salary according to that role) I want to make my `New Employee form` a bit more interactive: I want the `salary` field's value to change according to the `role` selected from the radio buttons group.

My form now looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@room) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, label: 'Full Name', :required => true %>
  <%= f.association :role, as: :radio_buttons, :required => true %>
  <%= f.input :salary, label: 'Salary', :required => true %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

And my `employees.js.coffee` file has this code:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#employee_employee_role_id_1').click ->
    $(document.getElementById('employee_salary')).val(15)
```

where I have the values hardcoded to make sure there was no problem with my form fields ids.

What I need is to have the `.click` method apply to all `#employee_employee_role_id_X` fields (where X is the number of each radio button) and the value passed to .val() to be `role.salary`

But, as the newbie I am to both Rails and js/jQuery, I am clueless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I managed to make this work but I am not confident at all that this is the best way. Here goes:

In the form, I just added `value_method: :salary`

```
<%= f.association :role, as: :radio_buttons, value_method: :salary, :required => true %>
```

and in my `.js.coffee` file:

```
jQuery ->
  $("input[name='role[role_id]']").change ->
    $(document.getElementById('salary')).val(($("input:radio[name='role[role_id]']:checked").val()))
```

Please feel free to comment or even provide a better answer if one exists! :)